# Big difference in performance looping through 1-1000 in PyCharm and PythonIDLE/Shell

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm, python-idle

Recently, when I was fiddling Python with different IDE/shells, I was most surprised at the performance differences among them.

The code I wrote is a simple for-loop through 1-1000. When executed by PythonIDLE or Windows Powershell, it took about **16 seconds** to finish it while PyCharm almost finished it immediately within about **500ms**.

I'm wondering why the difference is so huge.

```
for x in range(0, 1000, 1):
    print(x)
```

Comment: since this appears to only refer to powershell as the win10 console to _start_ python, does it make sense to tag this with "powershell"?

Comment: Show us the code, how you ran it and how you measured the time taken!

Comment: @Lee_Dailey You're right, I've removed the tag of PowerShell.

Comment: Looping is cheap. *Printing* is expensive.

Comment: @ Klaus D. Code included. I measured the time by both my personal feeling and a stopwatch.

Comment: You *seriously* need a faster computer if this code runs for 500ms (0.5s).

Comment: @iBug Emmmm, you're right, PyCharm finished it very fast, 500ms is not precise.

Comment: @preachers - thank you! [*grin*]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The time to execute the loop is almost zero.  The time you're seeing elapse is due to the printing, which is tied to the output facilities of the particular shell you are using.  For example, the sort of buffering it does, maybe the graphics routines being used to render the text, etc.  There is no practical application for printing numbers in a loop as fast as possible to a human-readable display, so perhaps you can try the same test writing to a file instead.  I expect the times will be more similar.

On my laptop your code takes 4.8 milliseconds if writing to the terminal.  It takes only 460 microseconds if writing to a file.

TL;DR: run stupid benchmarks, get stupid times.

Comment: It takes me as much as 51ms to write to the WSL terminal, with `time python3 -c '...'`

Comment: By writing to a file and then double click to run it with Python shell, the speed is as fast as within PyCharm.

Comment: I still don't understand one point that both file and statements in a terminal execute the Print function. So what makes it different in performance?

Comment: @iBug: You are including the time to launch and terminate Python.  I am using `%timeit` in IPython which is more accurate.

Comment: @preachers: Writing to the terminal can be slower because it goes all the way to your display.  Writing to a file is simpler--it's literally copying bytes, whereas writing to a display is a lot more complex.

Comment: But the file execution would also display all these numbers line by line, the screen provides the same result. Beside this, I don't see the difference between writing code in PyCharm and shell, they all have to print, but the performance is still largely different.

Comment: I think I've found the problem. It is graphic-related. PyCharm provides a simple display of the output with a black background and white characters in smaller font where the shell window has been configured to a more fancy theme. Besides that, I have a 4k display with an average graphic card, so that's the key issue. I've tried to change the shell theme configure and the performance changed too. Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 1):

IDLE is written in Python and uses tkinter, which wraps tcl/tk.  By default, IDLE runs your code in a separate process, with output sent through a socket for display in IDLE's Shell window.  So there is extra overhead for each print call.  For me, on a years-old Windows machine, the 1000 line prints take about 3 seconds, or 3 milliseconds per print.

If you print the the 1000 lines with one print call, as with

```
print('\n'.join(str(i) for i in range(1000)))
```

the result may take a bit more that 3 milliseconds but it is still subjectly almost 'instantaneous'.

Note: in 3.6.7 and 3.7.1, single 'large' prints, where 'large' can be customized by the user, are squeezed down to a label that can be expanded either in-place or in a separate window.